# "Docker" does not start after initial installation

Tags: docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop

Installed "Docker Desktop", opened and saw this error

```
Error details:
1 error occurred:
    * starting WSL integration service: synchronising agents: synchronising agent list: checking if desired distros are responsive: 1 error occurred:
    * running uname in "Ubuntu" distro: running WSL command "wsl.exe -d Ubuntu uname" failed with output "!\x048\x04A\x04B\x045\x04<\x045\x04 \x00=\x045\x04 \x00C\x044\x040\x045\x04B\x04A\x04O\x04 \x00=\x040\x049\x04B\x048\x04 \x00C\x04:\x040\x047\x040\x04=\x04=\x04K\x049\x04 \x00?\x04C\x04B\x04L\x04.\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00": exit status 0xffffffff
```

Tried this:
Reinstall Docker
wsl --unregister docker-desktop
wsl --shutdown

But it's all useless

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The problem was that `wsl` was using Ubuntu, which I removed a long time ago. I used `wsl --unregister` old "Ubuntu" and it worked.